# How to create a text file and append text to the existing file?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, save, savefiledialog, writealltext

I'm trying to save my textbox1 content into a text file to my computer.
What I want to do is to create a save directory and when it's set up, I will save the content of `textbox1` to that txt file.
Not just once, I want to append the content of the TextBox to the same file after.

`Button2`: Trying to browse and create a txt file.
`Button4` (1st click): This button will save the content of `textbox1` to the txt file created.
`Button4` (2nd click)": this will add the current content of `textbox1` to the same txt file.

But I want to be able to change the directory whenever I want.
I also want to choose path outside the code or outside the textbox.
Meaning, I want a button that will let me choose a folder where I want to create a text file.
The 2nd button will let me save the `textbox1` content to the created text file.

Here's some of my code but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly because it's now doing what I want. Please help.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim isave As New SaveFileDialog
        isave.Filter = "txt files (*.txt) |*.txt"
        isave.FilterIndex = 2
        isave.RestoreDirectory = False

        If isave.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            IO.File.WriteAllText(isave.FileName, TextBox1.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim theText As String
        theText = TextBox1.Text
        IO.File.AppendAllText("isave", Environment.NewLine & theText)
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to store the most recent `SaveFileDialog.FileName` and use it to append text to that file later on. You should also decide what to do in case the file doesn't exist at that point, since `File.AppendAllText()` creates a new one when the file specified is not there -- You should (really) declare the SaveFileDialog object with an `Using` statement

Comment: Oh, yes I have to prepare also if ever the txtfile is not on the directory.
But can you tell me the code for that? Can you correct my codes please.

Comment: @NewbieTJ Side note: You can also go into Visual Studio's own NuGet package manager and download the _Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell package_ . Then you have a modern SaveFileDialog.

Comment: Using SFD As New Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonSaveFileDialog()
            SFD.Title = "Your title"
            SFD.Filters.Add(New Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonFileDialogFilter("", ".txt"))
            If System.IO.Directory.Exists("your Path") Then
                SFD.InitialDirectory = "your Path"
            Else
                SFD.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            End If

Comment: If SFD.ShowDialog() = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                '...
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using

Comment: You can do the same for an OpenFileDialog. If you want this to be Multiselect then write OFD.Multiselect = True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to proceed:

- Use a Field (`lastSaveFileName` here) to store the path of the last file saved.
- Use a SaveFileDialog to get the file path, store the result in `lastSaveFileName`

  - The SaveFileDialog asks for confirmation if the file already exists. The user may choose to overwrite it or not
  - If the user chooses not to overwrite the existing file (hence cancels the operation), the `lastSaveFileName` is set to an empty string, so you cannot append new text to this file.
    **If this is not the behavior you're expecting** (i.e., you want to preserve and update a file created in a previous *session*), then remove `sfd.OverwritePrompt = True` and use `File.AppendAllText()` instead of `File.WriteAllText()`
- To update the selected file, adding more text, use the previously stored `lastSaveFileName` reference

  - If the file doesn't exist - at this time - or it has never been specified, prompt the user to create the file first. You could also store the file path in the Project's Settings

I've renamed the Buttons to `SaveFile` and `UpdateFile` and the TextBox to `TextContent`: it's always better to assign meaningful names to your Controls

The SaveFileDialog object must be declared with an `Using` statement, since you need to dispose of it when it's closed (a window shown with `ShowDialog()` cannot dispose of itself. Declaring a disposable object with an `Using` statement, ensures that the object is disposed even if an exception is raised in the meanwhile; most of the times)

```
Imports System.IO

Private lastSaveFileName As String = String.Empty

Private Sub SaveFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveFile.Click
    lastSaveFileName = GetSaveFileName(lastSaveFileName)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastSaveFileName) Then
        File.WriteAllText(lastSaveFileName, TextContent.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateFile.Click
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastSaveFileName) AndAlso File.Exists(lastSaveFileName) Then
        File.AppendAllText(lastSaveFileName, Environment.NewLine & TextContent.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(
            Me, "The file has not been created yet [other instructions]",
            "Save file missing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information
        )
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetSaveFileName(suggestedName As String) As String
    Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
        sfd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) |*.txt"
        sfd.FileName = suggestedName
        sfd.OverwritePrompt = True
        If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Return sfd.FileName
        End If
        Return String.Empty
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. This code works and really is a big help to my study program. Thank you for the explanation I'm learning. There is only one thing left.

Using your code, I was able to create a txtfile, I was able to update the content of the same txtfile but it's only I don't exit the app. I stop the program and run again, try to continue the update but it requires me to create new one since overwriting will delete my previous saved contents. How can I continue the update on the same txt file even after exiting the app? I want to continue when I get back. Please help.

Comment: It's described in the ***If this is not the behavior you're expecting*** section and, eventually, see the note about storing the selected path the Project' Settings (`My.Settings`), in case you need to preserve the last previously saved file path between runs

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry I think I need rest to fully understand and learn your shared knowledge. Thank you again. You really helped me.

Comment: I tried it but not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: I tried it but not sure if I did it correctly.
Is the `File.AppendAllText()`  gonna replace the `sfd.OverwritePrompt = True` in the `Private Function` or in `Private Sub SaveFile`?

I tried to replace the `File.WriteAllText` on SaveFile but it shows dialog if I want to replace the file on my last session.

Comment: I tried to put the code this way
`Using sfd As New SaveFileDialog()
            sfd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) |*.txt"
            sfd.FileName = suggestedName
            'sfd.OverwritePrompt = True
            File.AppendAllText(lastSaveFileName, TextContent.Text)
            If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                Return sfd.FileName
            End If
            Return String.Empty
        End Using
`

But it shows error:
ArgumentExpectation was unhandled
Empty path name is not legal.

Can you show me how to do it correctly?
Thank you.

Comment: Nope, `File.AppendAllText()` replaces `File.WriteAllText()` in `SaveFile_Click()`. In the `GetSaveFileName()` method, just set `sfd.OverwritePrompt = False`

Comment: Oh great! It's working. This is what I really want to happen. Thank you very much. You really are a big help. Now I can experiment again using this. Another learning hehe.